# Can't drag icons from second display

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, mouse, icons

I'm currently using a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, GNOME Version 3.36.8.

I have a monitor connected to my laptop. I can freely drag and move icons across my desktop on the main laptop display, but when I move them to the desktop on the monitor - it doesn't work, i can drag it but can't move it anywhere.

When I click on the icon, I can see that I'm moving it, when I release my mouse button - the file doesn't drop, it continues to be dragged but I can't put it anywhere. When I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or try to move it in another directory it just goes back where it was.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Same Gnome version (3.36.8) and same crazy anomaly. I can move the icons a single display ... but once I try to move it from one display to the other, the drag option locks and the folder is stuck to the mouse. I can't drop it no matter what I try. The lame thing is that if I move a folder too close to the border of my left screen - it jumps and lands on my right screen and I can't move it back no matter what I try to do.
Let me know if you get this figured out.